# Is there a way to backup AD and DNS in Windows 2008 without backing up the whole Volume?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I would like to know if there is a (cost free) way to backup Windows Server 2008 Active Directory and DNS settings without using Windows Server Backup.

The problem stems from not having a seperate volume available to store the resulting backup from Windows Server Backup.

I examined the command line options with wbadmin and it also expects the destination to be a dedicated volume for the backup.

~ED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the instructions in this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944530) to allow you to use the `wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backuptarget:c:` command to, for example, put a System State Backup (which 
is the way to [backup Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.05.adbackup.aspx)) onto the "C:" volume.

(To be a bit preachy: Putting your backup on the same volume being backed-up isn't real backup. Real backup is off-site and offline. Perhaps you're just testing or mocking something up, but don't rely on this for any real backup.)

Comment: Thanks for the info.

I reviewed wbadmin previously, and was hoping to be able to send the backup to a file so it could be compressed and shipped off site.

Is it possible to zip the resulting backup volume?

Comment: @EtherDragon: You could always try it and see what kind of compression ratio you get.

Comment: I finallyd ended up using this:
wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backuptarget:g: -quiet

The contents of the system backup volume can be compressed and shipped off site.